# Check if date is in coming month

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate

I'm setting a date to a certain birthdayTextField like so

```
@objc func birthdayDatePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    birthdayTextField.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

}
```

Now this textfield value is stored in coredata in a string attribute. There can be many such birthday dates stored in coredata. Now when I fetch these dates from the database, I want to show in a tableview only those dates which come in the following month.

How can it be achieved...?

Comment: Why do you store a date as a string? You should store it as a date object, not as a string.

Comment: .@Psytho Is it necessary to store date as a date object always..? Just asking since I'm not sure of it....

Comment: No. But doing this would let you easily know which dates are within a month from now.

Comment: it's not necessary, but it's more efficient, cause you'll be able easily to fetch the data from the CoreData ordered/filtered in any way using predicates.

Comment: Ok..as of now this is how I have saved to coredata...`newProdObj.setValue(self.birthdayTextField.text, forKey: "birthday")`. To save as a `nsdate` object will changing the coredata attribute (`birthday` in this case) from `string` to `Date` be enough or will anything else have to be changed...?

Comment: @v.bw You describe the date as “birthday dates” so unless your app is for expectant mothers, the date of birth will always be in the past.  Are you actually interested in the month/day, regardless of year?  I think that is one of those circumstances where storing as a date is unhelpful.  I would store the month and day instead (or as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution using the powerful date math abilities of `Calendar` together with `DateComponents` in a `Date` extension.

- It calculates the first day of next month with `nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:)` looking for `day == 1`
- It compares the given date with the first date of next month to the `month` granularity with `compare(:to:toGranularity:)`.

---

```
extension Date {
    func isDateInNextMonth() -> Bool {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let nextMonth = calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: DateComponents(day:1), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
        return calendar.compare(self, to: nextMonth, toGranularity: .month) == .orderedSame
   }
}
```

Use it simply in your method

```
sender.date.isDateInNextMonth()
```

---

Or – more versatile – according to the other *isDateIn...* methods as extension of `Calendar`

```
extension Calendar {
    func isDateInNextMonth(_ date : Date) -> Bool {
        let nextMonth = self.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: DateComponents(day:1), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!
        return self.compare(date, to: nextMonth, toGranularity: .month) == .orderedSame
    }
}
```

and use it

```
Calendar.current.isDateInNextMonth(sender.date)
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to check if the date is in the next 30 days it's still easier

```
extension Calendar {
    func isDateInNextThirtyDays(_ date : Date) -> Bool {
        return self.dateComponents([.month], from: Date(), to:date).month! < 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I get my date like so...`2018-03-29 18:30:00 +0000`. But when I print `Calendar.current.isDateInNextMonth(result.birthday!)` I'm getting `false`. Shouldn't I've got `true` since the date is well within next month... ?

Comment: From perspective of today (2018-03-23) next month is April (04)

Comment: No next month is in range April,1- April,30. You probably mean *check if date is in the next 30 days* which is something else.

Comment: Actually I wanted to include all dates from tomorrow till the next month...:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167429/discussion-between-v-bw-and-vadian).

Comment: It worked @vadian. Thank you very much. Have given an upvote also for the answer...:)